# Error: java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: php, android, json

an error said java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject, how can I convert it to a jsonobject

here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

    $query = "SELECT SUM(OrderPrice) as total FROM tbl_user";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$new_arr[] = $row['total'];
}
echo json_encode($new_arr);

?>
```

my android code:

```
                try{
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data =     jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.i("log_tag","total: "+json_data.getString("total"));

                        total.setText("total");





                    }
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
```

Comment: also put json sample that i knw which 1 cause problem

Answer (score 0):

In below line of code **result** is getting as string which is not properly formatted in JSON  that's why you are getting this error :

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Comment: dosent matter it autometically convert string in to array bro

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON will most likely be an array of numbers rather than a dictionary like

```
["23.00", "24.00"]
```

So when you get do

```
JSONObject json_data =     jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

You will just get a string back like "23.00". You are not getting back a JSON object. So it causes the exception. You should change it to:

```
String total = jArray.getString(i);
```

So just to confirm, your code should look like this:

```
try{
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
      String total = jArray.getString(i);

      Log.i("log_tag","total: "+total);

      total.setText(total);
   }
}catch(JSONException e){
   Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: it does not work the getString gets an error in
  Log.i("log_tag","total: "+json_data.getString("total"))

Comment: That is because you are getting the value by key. There is no key in this instance. If there was a key your JSON would look like ['total': '23.00', 'total':'24.00'].